# Reading Soap Request XML containing 20MB of doc file content in a xml tag/Attribute into Spring Integration application using around 500MB memory

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

In our application, we are using Spring Integration/Soap Web Service and Spring Boot.
We have flow in Spring integration which receives a input XML which has a tag called `<content>` which contains the data of the Document which we need to upload.
Since it is spring Integration we receive this XML data as Source Object.
we are converting this Source object into String xml. I see that the memory usage in JVM shoots upto 500MB when this Source to String transformation is happening though the content of the xml is just 20MB. Also in Visual VM I see huge memory usage by char [].

I have even tried with marshaller and marshaller inbound gateway but same issue.

```
**<int-ws:inbound-gateway id="uploadDocuments"
                            request-channel="uploaddoc" error-channel="errorChannel"
                            header-mapper="xyz"
                            marshaller="abcjaxbmarshaller"
                            unmarshaller="abcjaxbmarshaller"/>**
```

I even wrote a simple Filter just to see if the issue is related to Spring Integration but what i found is when i am reading the xml from the ServletRequest into String object the memory shoots up again to around 500MB.

```
@Component
public class UploadDocumentFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException { // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String test = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
        System.out.println("the input is " + test);

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

The request xml is Base64 encoded. I am not able to justify the increase in size for 20MB file to 500MB usage of memory. Could someone please explain me why there is so much rise in memory and the possible solution to this ?

Comment: Looks like you have faced a standard Java behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089364/why-does-reading-a-file-into-memory-takes-4x-the-memory-in-java

Comment: @ArtemBilan : In my case how do i solve this ? As this request xml is coming from a client application.  how should i control it at back end ?

Comment: Please, don't raise the same question again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70611209/memory-efficient-way-to-convert-source-object-staxsource-to-string-object-in-j. I'm not sure that there is a way to really have result as a string and in-memory. You really just load the whole content into memory. The string has no way to be outside of heap. See the linked question in my previous comment for possible solutions.

Comment: Try saving your request xml to a local file by writing each line to an output stream (don't read every line into a string which is in memory).  Then pass the file name in the spring integration message instead of the content.  Whatever processes that file should stream the file contents and not load it all in memory, possibly by parsing the file using stax (https://www.baeldung.com/java-stax)